# Using Keras fit_generator gives an error of wrong shape

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

I am getting an error on *fit_generator*. My generator returns the following:

```
yield(row.values, label)
```

For example, using it:

```
myg = generate_array()
for i in myg:
    print((i[0].shape))
    print(i)
    break

(9008,)
(array([0.116516, 0.22419 , 0.03373 , ..., 0.      , 0.      , 0.      ]), 0)
```

But the following throws an exception:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(84, activation='relu', input_dim=9008))

ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_1_input to have shape 
(9008,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

Any idea?

Comment: You should make a self contained example that shows the problem, because with the code you have shown, we cannot guess what the problem is.

Comment: data generator needs to give a batch of data, not a single sample.  See e.g.: https://stanford.edu/~shervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly

Comment: @Kota Mori - Thanks! that did the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by Kota Mori: data generator needs to give a batch of data, not a single sample. See e.g.: https://stanford.edu/~shervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly

Since I want a stochastic gradient descent (batch size is one) the following code fixed the problem:

```
def generate_array():
   while True:
    X = np.empty((1, 9008))
    y = np.empty((1), dtype=int)
    # Some processing
    X[0] = row
    y[0] = label
    yield(X,y)
```